# How to make API server calls in a Capacitor native app?

Tags: android, ios, api, axios, capacitor

How do you make **API** server **calls using Axios** in a **Capacitor native app** on Android or iOS (including on emulators)?

Answer (score 0):

In your main `index.js` file of your React app you need to **globally define** a **`baseUrl`** for axios so that all (relative) axios calls reach the server correctly:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://www.example.com';
```

as per the documentation: https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults - otherwise Capacitor will point it to the `localhost`, which gave me problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running ionic angular you can use ionics HTTP (its a cordova plugin but it works well with capacitor) and make a http interceptor (must be the last interceptor if you have other interceptor and for web just use handleNext) if not i think you could still use the http community plugin available in capacitor